# TaskCreationOptions.AttachedToParent not make patent Task wait for child

Tags: c#

According to book `Kort W. - Exam Ref 70-483. Programming in C#` parent thread should always wait for child ones and bring as result:

`0
1 
2`

But in most cases I have

`0
0 
0`

I was expecting that TaskCreationOptions.AttachedToParent will make main thread wait for child ones.

```
public static void parenThr()
{

    Task<Int32[]> parent = Task.Run
    (
        () =>
        {
            var results = new Int32[3];

            new Task(() => results[0] = 0, TaskCreationOptions.AttachedToParent).Start();
            new Task(() => results[1] = 1, TaskCreationOptions.AttachedToParent).Start();
            new Task(() => results[2] = 2, TaskCreationOptions.AttachedToParent).Start();

            return results;
        }
    );

    parent.ContinueWith(
        (s) =>
        {
            foreach (var i in s.Result)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("res {0}",i);
            }
        }
    );

}
```

Why main thread not waits for child ones completion?

Comment: Doesn't Task.Run start by default with `DenyChildAttach`?

Comment: I can't reproduce the behaviour you describe. I call your method straight from `static void main` and then I call `Console.ReadLine();` and it results in `0 1 2` constantly.

Comment: Quote: "Parent tasks implicitly prevent child tasks from attaching to them if they are created by calling the Task.Run method".  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/attached-and-detached-child-tasks?view=netframework-4.7.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default [Task.Run](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/threading/Tasks/Task.cs,5614) starts with `TaskCreationOptions.DenyChildAttached`.

From [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.taskcreationoptions?view=netframework-4.7.2):

> **TaskCreationOptions.DenyChildAttached**
>
> Specifies that any child task that attempts to execute as an attached
>   child task (that is, it is created with the AttachedToParent option)
>   will not be able to attach to the parent task and will execute instead
>   as a detached child task. For more information, see Attached and
>   Detached Child Tasks.

You should use `Task.Factory.StartNew`, so you can specify your own arguments.

```
public static async Task Do()
{
    Task<int[]> parent = Task.Factory.StartNew
    (
        () =>
        {
            var results = new int[3];

            Task.Factory.StartNew(() => results[0] = 0, default(CancellationToken), TaskCreationOptions.AttachedToParent, TaskScheduler.Default);
            Task.Factory.StartNew(() => results[1] = 1, default(CancellationToken), TaskCreationOptions.AttachedToParent, TaskScheduler.Default);
            Task.Factory.StartNew(() => results[2] = 2, default(CancellationToken), TaskCreationOptions.AttachedToParent, TaskScheduler.Default);

            return results;
        }
    , default(CancellationToken), TaskCreationOptions.None, TaskScheduler.Default);

    var ints = await parent;

    foreach (var i in ints)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("res {0}", i);
    }
}
```

To avoid potential confusion with which `TaskScheduler` is used, you should use overload with TaskScheduler parameter.

Comment: Can I assume that in my case `default(CancellationToken)` is the same like constructor call for `new CancellationToken()` ?

Comment: @vico Because CancellationToken is a struct, `default(CancellationToken)` is the same as `new Cancellation(Token)` , but shorter and since C#7.1 you can just write `default`